# Looping a Macro through a given range where it will transpose a cloumn to a row and split the cell contents in a row?

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to transpose a column values to a row and split the values in one of the cells as rows. Here is what I am trying to do:

Input Data:

```
09/20/2013
$240
Item1, Item2, Item3
```

Output Data:

```
09/20/2013 $80 Item1
09/20/2013 $80 Item2
09/20/2013 $80 Item3
```

The value is dependent on the number of items. It is $80 * Number of items. I have to split the items' cell and transpose them into rows. I am unable to do this using a macro.

Comment: so what have you tried? how is your question programming related? Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results. See also: [Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe a little overkill but try this:

```
Sub SplitUp()
  Dim rng As Range
  Set rng = [A1:A3]

  Dim sx() As String
  sx = Split(rng(3, 1).Value, ",")

  Dim cntr As Integer
  cntr = 1

  Dim money As Long
  money = rng(2, 1).Value / (UBound(sx) + 1)

  For i = LBound(sx) To UBound(sx)
    Range("C" & cntr).Value = rng(1, 1) & " $" & money & " " & sx(i)
    cntr = cntr + 1
  Next
End Sub
```

Result looks like this:

[image]